# Symfony validator throws exception on invalid Collection

Tags: php, validation, symfony

The symfony validator throws an exception when I attempt to validate a scalar using a Collection constraint. I would expect it to return a violation instead.

Example code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;

$validator = Validation::createValidator();

$input = 'testtesttest';
$constraints = [
    new Collection([
        'fields' => [
            'one' => new Length(array('min' => 10))
        ]
    ])
];

$violationList = $validator->validate($input, $constraints);
```

throws

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException: Expected argument of type "array or Traversable and ArrayAccess", "string" given in vendor/symfony/validator/Constraints/CollectionValidator.php:37
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

For other Constraint classes (e.g. NotBlank, Type) the validator adds to the violation list when it encounters something invalid. To have it throw an exception instead in the case of a Collection seems bizarre to me. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for responding a year after but I was stuck with the same issue.

The solution for me was to create a [custom Validation Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html).

Firstly you have to create a custom constraint: `CustomCollection` which will contain the following code (note that my class is extending the [Collection constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Collection.html) and not the default [Constraint](https://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraint.html) class):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Collection;

class CustomCollection extends Collection
{
    public $message = 'You must provide an array.';
}
```

Then you have to implement your custom constraint's logic (in this case validate that your value is a valid array) :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\CollectionValidator;

class CustomCollectionValidator extends CollectionValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!\is_array($value)) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->addViolation();
            return;
        }
        parent::validate($value, $constraint);
    }
}
```

Now if I take your code as example, you have to change the constraint from `Collection` to `CustomCollection` in order to get a violation :

```
$input = 'testtesttest';
$constraints = [
    new CustomCollection([
        'fields' => [
            'one' => new Length(array('min' => 10))
        ]
    ])
];

$violationList = $validator->validate($input, $constraints);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the `Collection` constraint. This constraint is meant for validating collections (e.g. array, a traversable object).

You should pass an array of constraints to the validate method.

E.g.:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;

$validator = Validation::createValidator();

$input = 'testtesttest';
$constraints = [
    new Length(array('min' => 10)),
    // ... And other constraints
];

$violationList = $validator->validate($input, $constraints);
```

You can see more info about the validator here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html#usage

Comment: I realise that it's meant for validating collections, but if it gets an invalid collection then I'd expect it to return a violation, not throw an exception.

Comment: For example say I'm expecting an array like this `$array = ['x' => ['a' => (int), 'b' => (string)]]`. I need to use a Collection constraint to make sure the values of $array['x'] are good, but if I get `['x' => 5]` as an input then the validator falls over

Comment: Validation is meant for validating the data, not the schema of the data. You could always do some `try{...}catch(){}` around the validation.

Comment: With Collection you can set validation rules for each element in an array/Traversable, and specifically allow/disallow extra or missing fields. Isn't that validating the schema?

Comment: `try {...} catch () {}` is not useful for complex arrays, as you can't tell where the exception was triggered